# How to make more than one layer container in plotting in nokia here map?

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I need your help..
How i can make more than one layer of container in nokia here map then put some id of it..
I am using Polyline to draw my gps tracks

This is my code this time..

```
var coords = [],
// Loop to add all the coordinates to an array
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
coords.push(parseFloat(val.latitude));
coords.push(parseFloat(val.longitude));
});

// Now create the Polyline
salesmanTrackPoints = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
pen: {
strokeColor: "#22CA",
lineWidth: 5
},
arrows: true
});
map.objects.add(salesmanTrackPoints);
```

i hope you can give some answer.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple `Polylines` **directly** onto the map to draw separate tracks like this:

```
track1 = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
  pen: {
    strokeColor: "#22CA",
    lineWidth: 5
  },
  arrows: true
});

track2 = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
  pen: {
    strokeColor: "#22CA",
    lineWidth: 5
  },
  arrows: true
});

map.objects.addAll([track1, track2]);
```

Alternatively you could use a [container](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Container.html) to separate out the `MapObjects` into logical collections e.g.:

```
var container1 = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
  container2 = new nokia.maps.map.Container(),

map.objects.add(container1);
map.objects.add(container2);

// Add Objects to container 1.
container1.objects.addAll([track1, markerA, markerB]);
// Add Other Objects to container 2.
container1.objects.addAll([track2, markerX, markerY]);
```

You can then retrieve the various `MapObjects` with the Container using the [OList](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.util.OList.html) interface.

Since this is JavaScript, there is no problem with adding additional properties directly onto the `Polyline` objects if you wish:

```
polyline = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(coords, {
      myCustomProperty : "I like Thursdays",
      mySecondCustomId : "Thurs",
      pen: {
        strokeColor: "#22CA",
        lineWidth: 5
      },
      arrows: true
    });
```